# Nagios Core Acknowledgement notification (email)

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios

Nagios Core 3.X on RHEL. I want to know how to send an email to the relevant contact group when someone Acks an alert.

Comment: http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/notifications.html I believe is what you're asking for. You want to send a notification when a check has been acknowledged, right?

Answer (score 0):

The variable for the acknowledgement details is "Notes: $SERVICEACKCOMMENT$"  I found this out here: http://kylepikelinux.blogspot.com/search/label/$SERVICEACKCOMMENT$%20acknowledgment%20Nagios%20email%20alerts

I realized we had it set already, but literally noone was Acking anything O_o